# How do I run GKART?

Tags: pc, technical-issues

I've downloaded and installed [GKART](http://gkart.garena.com/main/) but now I can't figure out how to run the game.

Two icons were added to my desktop, one is Garena Messenger and one is gkart, but running any of them only opens a login window which ends up in garena messenger. I know the game is installed since there is a folder with size around 1GB in my installation path named GKart, and that can't be only a messenger.

Does any one know how can I start the game itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is region: GKART is released only for Singapore. It seems there is a link to start game somewhere in applications installed with GKART, but it's only available for those who are in Singapore.

Comment: Garena's [Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/GarenaGOKart/posts/203817739653700) suggests that GKART servers are now open to other countries in addition to Singapore. [The Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GKART) suggests that Malaysia, Australia, and the US are included, but I could not find independent verification of this.